# How do I disable the VGA port?

Tags: vga

Is it possible to disable the VGA port on a system, or otherwise prevent projectors and external monitors from being used? on windows 7
I want my laptop to prevent it from or deny if VGA cord is tried to connect to my laptop vga port. is any software or codes available, I am interested in develop such software. plz guide me

Comment: What's your usecase? _Why_ do you want to disable the port?

Comment: Also, what kind of hardware and OS are we talking about here? Remember to [edit your question with the additional information](https://superuser.com/posts/992811/edit).

Comment: windows 7 ,I want my laptop to prevent itself or deny if VGA cord is tried to connect to my laptop vga port. is any software or codes available, I am interested in develop such software. plz guide me

Comment: is it possible ?

Comment: You still haven’t provided the reason. “I don’t want it” is not a reason. And no, it’s most likely not possible.

Comment: suppose I have a video player software,  while I playing my video file through that software I want my player  (software) to disable the VGA or HDMI ports automatically  so that it could not projected or seen in any other monitor. i want it only to be watched on my default screen of my laptop.

Comment: is it possible to develop such software or any such exists ?

Comment: Please don’t spam the comment section. This is not a chat. No, it is not possible. You can, however, stop playback when you detect the monitor configuration has changed. How you’d do that is probably a question for [so].

Comment: @DanielB That sounds like an answer to me!

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the question was to prevent any video connection or fully disable the VGA port. I'm confused as to why answering this question required such information instead of wasting this user's time by interrogating them when the end product became "No it is not possible." Anyway...

@Jogesh I am unaware of any port disabling that can be done without disabling the built in graphics of the computer. If you would like to disable a projector or TV from displaying, most have an AV mute that can be found on the remote or the device.

Answer (score 2):

I know multiple ways to do this:

1. Right click anywhere on the desktop, select graphics options, --> Output to --> Intel Dual Display clone --> Notebook+Monitor --> turn off the external display prior to disconnecting cable --> Select Graphic options, Output to, Notebook.
2. Start >> Control Panel; then look for Graphics Properties
3. You may have a monitor icon on the lower right side of your screen. Right-click on this icon to see what options are available. Or left double-click to quicky access your Graphics Properties.
   If you have Intel graphics, you may be able to quickly access your Graphics Properties with the following hot-key combination:  CTRL+ALT+F12.

Comment: Not everyone's control panel has an item called "Graphics Properties". "Display" and "Device Manager" on the other hand are universal to Windows XP through to Windows 10.